# About the $C^{1,1} $regularity of the boundary of a set

Tags: convex-geometry

I am studying a paper that uses the following property :

Consider $U$ and $V$ open, bounded and convex domains in $R^n$ with $U \supset \overline{V}$ and suppose that $min_{y \in V} |x - y| = \lambda > 0$ ($\lambda$ is independent of $x$) for all $x \in \partial U$. Then the $\partial U$ is $C^{1,1}$ from inside. The authors doens't say a reference for this. I searched a lot for a reference for this property, but I didn't find anything...

Someone could point me a reference (or give a proof)?

thanks for your attention

Observation: A time ago I asked a similar question(and maybe help :   mathoverflow.net/q/184713/55893 ), but I dont see how to use to proof in the case $C^{1,1}$

Comment: This seems to be a follow-up to a recent question: http://mathoverflow.net/q/184713/55893

Comment: you're right ! i will add this. thanks for your commentary